# AWS Cognito - returning user - how to design well

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito, sign

I have a question relating designing a Cognito Authentication and its flow in my app.

I managed to get logging in etc. However, a great "pain" happens when I have to reauthenticate users (as they access expires every 60 minutes as we all know). Now I am thinking how to solve it for a returning user.

1. Set a service which would every 59 minutes relog the user (if he does not sign out) - do it somehowe all the time in the background.
   a) how not to lose it when the app is turned on?
2. Set in the SplashScreen automatical relog - everytime I turn on the app, I relog in the background (update my session). This can work after a long time, as Refresh Token is valid for 30 days. After 30 days of not using the app we might expect the user to write down his details again. However, how to get a Refresh Token from a previous session? I would not like to store it in SharedPreferences or anything like that.

Which one to choose? What advice would you give me?

Thank you in advance!

Grzegorz

Answer (score 0):

When you successfully authenticate, do you get a refresh token? The access token expires after 60 minutes, but you can use the refresh token to get new access token without re-authentication.

Comment: Hey I do get it, but I am not sure how to use it. I was circulating around this idea: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html but is it the right one? I cannot find the java version of this code as well :/

Comment: That is the correct way to do it and these APIs are part of AWS Java SDK https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/

Comment: is there any tutorial around with it? I am sort of stuck with it. I tried also with Identity provider, but this cannot work, still needs to log in. I just want to log in the user automatically when he reopens the app and was signed in before (for which I can get a boolean form shared Preferences). How to do it :/ I am honestly stuck with my flow.

Comment: I cannot find it there